# Toggle children in a React stateless component

Tags: reactjs

I was using a stateful component but upon making it stateless I am unclear how/if I can toggle inner fields:

Here's a contrived example. I am actually working with `react-redux-form` and need to toggle certain input fields based on some radios.

```
const Sample = (props) => {

  let show = true
  const toggleMethod = (model, value) => {
    show = !show
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Control changeAction={toggleMethod} />
      { show === 'cc' ? <CCFIelds /> : null }

    </div>
    )
}
```

The toggle method works great but it will not rerender. Am I obliged to use state for this or is there a way to do it as is?

Comment: If you use redux, you need to `dispatch` an action to change the app state. State changed, components re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

When @Jason Xu say you can dispatch to change state, it's a way to influence parent and cause rerender, but you don't have to redux.

The easiest way is to let parent (smart container) own and control the `show` variable, and then pass to your stateless component as a prop. Define the `toggleMethod()` in parent, and pass down also.

To summarize:

1. `show` toggled in parent
2. `prop` changes
3. stateless component rerenders

Comment: I don't see how that would work unless my parent has state else I am in the same boat. Changes in a variable don't cause a rerender so the child will not get an updated prop

Comment: @Yashua So I have said, "parent" owns show variable, which means parent does have a state. Otherwise things like React.render() on root component would work, but like you said, it's anti-pattern thinking.